# How to perform a TukeyHSD test in Matlab and get the grouped pairs using letters?

Tags: matlab, statistics

How to perform a TukeyHSD post-hoc test after the Anova in Matlab, and get a table with the sorted grouped pairs using letters?

Example:

X has 3 treatments (columns) obtained in 4 replications (rows):

```
x=[9 1 3.1
   5 2 3.2
   7 1.1 3
   8 1.2 3]
```

The one-way ANOVA:

```
[p,a,s] = anova1(x)
```

And the multcompare result:

```
[c,m,h,nms] = multcompare(s)
```

[image]

How to get a result like this?

```
treatment   mean      Tukey_group
1           7.2500    a
2           1.3250    b
3           3.0750    b
```

Please see a similar example in R:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31547/how-to-obtain-the-results-of-a-tukey-hsd-post-hoc-test-in-a-table-showing-groupe

Answer (score 2):

I think I have a solution. I developed a Matlab function for this:

**Example:**

```
x=[9.0 1.0 3.1
5.0 2.0 3.2
7.0 1.1 3.0
8.0 1.2 3.0];
```

Sorting x in crescent order

```
[me or]=sort(mean(x),2);
xo=x(:,or);
```

ANOVA

```
[p,a,s] = anova1(xo);
```

Multcompare using HSD Tukey at 5% significance:

```
[c,m,h,nms] = multcompare(s,'alpha',0.05,'ctype','hsd');
```

Post-hoc grouping using the developed function:

```
phg = phgroup(xo,c);
```

The developed function phgroup:

```
function phg = phgroup(xo,c)
%
% Input:
% x: data matrix with treatments in rows and observations in columns
% c: matrix of pairwise comparison results from multcompare test
% 
% WARNING: is indispensable that the means of x matrix are sorted in crescent order.
%


% Getting significant pairwise comparisons
gr=1;
for i=1:size(c,1)
if c(i,3)>0&&c(i,5)>0||c(i,3)<0&&c(i,5)<0
tt(c(i,2),c(i,1))=0;
gr=gr+1;
else
tt(c(i,1),c(i,1))=gr;
tt(c(i,2),c(i,1))=gr;
end
end

% Setting groups if all non-significant
if isempty(find(tt>0))==1
for i=1:size(tt,1)
    gr=gr+1;
    tt(i,i)=gr;
end
end

% Setting groups if some non-significant
for i=1:size(tt,1)
    if isempty(find(tt(i,:)>0))==1
        tt(i,i)=gr+1;
        gr=gr+1;
    end
end

% Correcting repeated groups
for i=1:size(tt,2)-1
    if max(find(tt(:,i+1)>0))==max(find(tt(:,i)>0))
        tt(find(tt(:,i+1)>0),i+1)=tt(i,i);
    end
end
mx=max(tt);
for i=1:size(tt,2)-1
    if max(tt(:,i+1))==mx(i)
        tt(find(tt(:,i+1)>0),i+1)=0;
    end
end

% Setting sequential groups
[B,IX] = sort(nonzeros(max(tt))');
for l=1:size(tt,1)
    for c=1:size(tt,2)
        if tt(l,c)>0
            for u=1:size(B,2)
                if tt(l,c)==B(u)
                    tt(l,c)=IX(u);
                end
            end
        end
    end
end

% Assigning letters to groups
gn=['a';'b';'c';'d';'e';'f';'g';'h';'i';'j';'k';'l';'m';'n';'o';'p';'q';'r';'t';'u';'v';'w';'x';'y';'z'];
for i=1:size(tt,1)
tg=[];
    ttu=nonzeros(unique(tt(i,:)))';
    for j=1:size(ttu,2)
            tg=[tg gn(ttu(1,j))];
            TG{i,1}=tg;
    end
end

% Getting output table
m1=[mean(xo);std(xo)]';
m1=[num2cell(m1) TG];
me1=['mean';m1(:,1)];
st=['std';m1(:,2)];
gr=['group';m1(:,3)];
phg=[me1 st gr];
```